# Can I replicate already replicated Kafka topic across another clusters?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication, confluent-platform

i have 3 Kafka Cluster and i'v replicated a topic in other Clsuter. 
Cluster 1 topic "test"

Cluster 2 `test.replica` .. i'v replicated this topic in Cluster 3 but when i send Data to topic "test" i can read the Data just from topic "test.replica"
topic test.replica.replica seems to be empty

Cluster 3 `test.replica.replica`

Connector

```
{
    "name":"test-z1-z2",
    "config":{
            "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector",
            "tasks.max":"4",
            "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
            "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
            "src.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9092",
            "src.zookeeper.connect":"localhost:2181",
            "dest.zookeeper.connect":"localhost:2182",
            "topic.whitelist":"test",
            "topic.rename.format":"test.replica",
            "confluent.license":""
    }
}
```

```
{
        "name":"test-z2-z3",
        "config":{
                "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector",
                "tasks.max":"4",
                "key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
                "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.replicator.util.ByteArrayConverter",
                "src.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"localhost:9093",
                "src.zookeeper.connect":"localhost:2182",
                "dest.zookeeper.connect":"localhost:2183",
                "topic.whitelist":"test.replica",
                "topic.rename.format":"test.replica.replica",
                "confluent.license":""
        }
}
```

Cluster 1

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
__confluent.support.metrics
__consumer_offsets
__consumer_timestamps
test
```

Cluster 2

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2182
__confluent.support.metrics
__consumer_offsets
test.replica
[root@localhost bin]# 
[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-topics --list --zookeeper localhost:2183
__confluent.support.metrics
__consumer_offsets
test.replica.replica
```

Producting data

```
[root@localhost bin]# seq 10 | ./kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Consuming the replica

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic test.replica
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Trying the other replica

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9094 --topic test.replica.replica

(no Data)
```

I want to send the Data to one Cluster and from there replicate it again across other Clusters.

Comment: Why replicate from the replica? Just run two replicators from your source to two different clusters...

Comment: Also, `rename.format` should probably just be `${topic}.replica`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the replicated data already got to the broker, and you're pointing at the latest offsets.

You can add `--from-beginning` to consume from the beginning offsets.

The real check would be to use `OffsetShell` to look at the topic's actual offsets. Besides, the destination topic was created correctly, so the replicator at least is working on that part.

It's also not clear if your connector configs are part of the same Connect cluster. Are you running `connect-disributed` on different ports, with different `bootstrap.servers` as well?

Comment: Thanks for your Replay. i'v replicated 2 Times. one time to the Aggregator Cluster and from The Aggregator to another one.

Comment: I can see that from your question. I'm not sure why you'd want to, but, does it work?